# How can you create a new svelte component in a test file

Tags: svelte, playwright

I am writing component tests for Svelte using Playwright.

One of my components takes another component as a prop

```js
    export let tabs: { label: string; content: typeof SvelteComponent }[];
```

I want to test it using something like

```js
test('Tabs renders first content', async ({ mount }) => {
    const component = await mount(Tabs, {
        props: {
            tabs: [
                { label: 'First Tab', content: FirstTabContent },
                { label: 'Second Tab', content: SecondTabContent }
            ]
        }
    });
    await expect(component).toContainText('First Tab Content');
});
```

However, I cannot find a way to populate `FirstTabContent` and `SecondTabContent`

Is there something like

```js
    const FirstTabContent = new SvelteComponent('<p>First Tab Content</p>');
```

that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without additional dependencies is to define the components in separate files and import them (e.g. `FirstTabContent.svelte`).

There are also packages like [svelte-htm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-htm) that allow you to define components inline for exactly this purpose:

```js
import html from 'svelte-htm';

test('Tabs renders first content', async ({ mount }) => {
    const component = await mount(Tabs, {
        props: {
            tabs: [
                { label: 'First Tab', content: html`First Tab Content` },
                { label: 'Second Tab', content: html`Second Tab Content` }
            ]
        }
    });
    await expect(component).toContainText('First Tab Content');
});
```